How to exclude field record wildcard imports from ghc -Wmissing-import-lists?
I'd like to get the behavior of -Xmissing-import-lists but exclude record field wildcard imports.
Example: $ ghc -XNoImplicitPrelude -Wmissing-import-lists {a,b,c}.hs
a.hs:
import Prelude (putStrLn, Bool(..))
main = putStrLn "Hi"

b.hs:
import Prelude (putStrLn)
main = putStrLn "Hi"

c.hs:
import Prelude
main = putStrLn "Hi"

Expect:

a.hs and b.hs no warning.
c warning.

Alternatively, I'd be interested if there is some way to enable NoFieldSelectors where it would be sufficient to import only the record and still be able to refer to its field via OverloadedRecordDot.

I think they moved in the opposite direction: originally a.hs was allowed: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/1789

The (..) in Bool(..) has nothing to do with records. (Nevertheless the intent of the question is clear.)

@DanielWagner I have tried looking up the definition of (..) as used in the import but couldn't find it. Can you point me to it? I undertstand and use it as record selectors import.

@JanMatejka It imports the associated names that go along with top level name being imported. In this case that would be the constructors of the Bool type (True and False). It would also import any record field names if Bool had any, but it doesn't.

Oh, that's right. I used Bool here as an example and didn't realize it is not a record. Ok, now I think that syntactically I'm referring generally to cnames in an import statement. Possibly vars as well. But where it comes up the most for me are the record fields imports.

I think this is actually an XY problem. I think what I really want is linting mechanism that works like -Wmissing-imports but only for the dependencies of the package. Internal imports should be -Wno-missing-imports. I expanded more about it at https://github.com/jan-matejka/code-golf/issues/47
